# Font Awesome use inside the Yii2 SideNavbar

Tags: yii2, navbar, font-awesome

I have followed the guidelines given by GitHub [Yii2 fontawesome](https://github.com/rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome) and successfully installed via composer. My problem is the code they given to get the specific icon to my SideNavbar is not working for me.

I have used **FA::icon('home')** inside my SideNav menu but this code out put only **">** this. not the home icon.

code which i was used in my sidenav menu.

```
<?= SideNav::widget([
'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
'heading' => 'System Functions',
'items' => [
    [
        'url' => '../dashboard/manager',
        'label' => Yii::t('app','Dashboard'),
        'icon' => 'home',   
        'active' => ($currentpage == 'Manager')
    ],
    [
        'url' => '#',
        'label' => 'Purchase',
        'icon' => FA::icon('home'),                       
         'items' => [
                [
                  'url' => '../dashboard/suppliers',
                  'label' => Yii::t('app','Suppliers'), 
                  'icon'=>'transport',                                
                  'active' => ($currentpage == 'Suppliers')
                ],
                [
                    'url' => '../dashboard/leaf-entry',
                    'label' => 'Leaf Collection', 
                    'icon'=>'leaf', 
                    'active' => ($currentpage == 'Leaf')
                ],
                [
                    'url' => '../dashboard/payments',
                    'label' => 'Payments', 
                    'icon'=>'phone', 
                    'active'=> ($currentpage == 'Payments') 
                ],
                ['label' => 'Reports', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#']
         ],
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Stock',
        'icon' => 'question-sign',
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Live Stock', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Auction Despatch', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Production Tracker', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Reports', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#']
          ],
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Human Resource',
        'icon' => 'question-sign',
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Employees', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Time Tracker', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Payments', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Reports', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#']
          ],
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'End of day calculations',
        'icon' => 'question-sign',
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Water Basis', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Dry Basis', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Out Turn', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Refuced Tea', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#']
          ],
    ],
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

Output

[image: SideNavbar]

And I also have used the Chrome DevTools to inspect the element, which gives me the below result. Hope this would be the problem.

[image: Element inspected in Chrome DevTools]

Comment: The screenshot shows the Chrome DevTools, not Firebug, so I've changed the question to reflect that. I'm not familiar with Yii2, though why do you use `FA::icon('home')` and not just a string like `'home'` like you did for the other icons?

Comment: Yes my mistake, other icons are bootstrap icons it has very few icons set so i don't need those

Comment: If answer is helpful for you and your problem is resolved now then please mark is as true. so this will be helpful for other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `SideNav::widget`, which uses the default icon prefix as `"glyphicon glyphicon-"`. This is a SideNav property. If you are creating a SideNav using a `glyphicon` icon, then it will only use `glyphicon` icons. If you want to use Font Awesome icons, you need to change the icon prefix like this:

```
      echo SideNav::widget([
        'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
        'heading' => 'System Functions',
        'iconPrefix' => ' ',
        'items' => [
        [
            'url' => '#',
            'label' => 'Home',
            'icon' => 'fa fa-home',
        ]
    ]
]);
```

You can use only one type of icons at a time.